# Automatically activate Countdown when moving to activity

Tags: java, android

When the 2nd activity start, I want a countdown timer to activate automatically.

Comment: `onStart` or `onCreate`. Either should work, so please show your code

Answer (score 0):

After your activity is loaded and the contents are set
add this code below:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```